# Tasks and data structures

Tags: data-structures, parallel-processing, task

Could anyone explain me what could be the advantages of encapsulating a data structure in a task in context of parallel computing. What does it even mean in the first place !

Comment: could you please be more elaborate. It looks like a random sentence was formed using three tags